Is it possible to apply one-way sync between a master spreadsheet and partial copies of it using Google Sheets?
I am deeply sorry I have to ask this question mainly because searching Google always pointed me to the wrong direction. Also, this is not a programming question per se. In fact, I would like an answer with the least possible code involved.
Figure 1 pictures the problem in its initial phase:

What I have is a master spreadsheet (about 5000 rows) from which a number of partial copies are generated, each for a different salesman so that he can see only the rows that concern him (for example, in the figure, the spreadsheet is split in half.)
How the copies are generated is of no concern to me -it's the director's job to do it manually or otherwise. The important thing is that each row has a unique key (first column) and that key is guaranteed to be preserved in all spreadsheets. The formatting and layout remains the same across all spreadsheets, too. Each spreadsheet is a different file and all those files are meant to be stored online as Google Sheets. The master spreadsheet gets updated periodically (again, by an external process of no concern to me) and when this happens the director starts preparing the partial copies. Once they are ready it shares them to the salesmen.
Figure 2 pictures what happens when salesmen start editing their partial spreadsheets.

For example, salesman 1 has changed "Value 2" to "Value 22" in row with key 1 and salesman 2 has changed "Value 12" to "Value 19" in row with key 4. When values are edited the master spreadsheet should be updated to reflect the changes. The update should happen automatically or semi-automatically. Also, it would be nice if updated cells are highlighted (using colors for example) so it's easy for the director to see what's been changed.
Is there any mechanism that can be applied to implement this workflow? It's alright if it involves some scripting as long as it is transparent to the users of the spreadsheets. I've tried with Google Apps Scripts but it is more of a joke than a solution: it is slow and unreliable. Anyway, here's the script that updates the cells in the master spreadsheet:
// ID of the master spreadsheet
var masterSheetId = 'MASTER_SHEET_ID';

// The name of the tab in each shared sheet
var tabName = 'Sheet1'; 

// Function to sync updates from partial to master
function syncPartial1() {
  syncRowsById(masterSheetId, tabName);
}

// Sync specific rows based on Column 1 (ID) and color the updated cells
function syncRowsById(masterSheetId, sheetName) {
  var partialSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName); 

  // Get data from the partial sheet
  var partialData = partialSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var partialIds = partialData.map(row => row[0]); // Get all values from Column 1 (ID)
  
  // Get data from the master sheet
  var masterSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(masterSheetId);
  var masterSheet = masterSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var masterData = masterSheet.getDataRange().getValues(); // Get all data from master
  var masterIds = masterData.map(row => row[0]); // Get all values from Column 1 (ID)

  // Loop through partial data
  for (var i = 1; i < partialData.length; i++) {
    var partialRow = partialData[i];
    var partialId = partialIds[i]; // ID from Column 1

    // Check if the ID exists in the master sheet
    var rowIndexInMaster = masterIds.indexOf(partialId);

    if (rowIndexInMaster > -1) {
      // Get the current row in the master sheet
      var masterRow = masterData[rowIndexInMaster];
      
      // Update the corresponding row in the master sheet and color changed cells
      for (var j = 1; j < partialRow.length; j++) {
        if (partialRow[j] !== masterRow[j]) { // If the cell value is different
          // Update the cell
          masterSheet.getRange(rowIndexInMaster + 1, j + 1).setValue(partialRow[j]);
          
          // Color the updated cell (e.g., light yellow)
          masterSheet.getRange(rowIndexInMaster + 1, j + 1).setBackground('#FFFF99');
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

What I am trying to avoid is having to move from those spreadsheets (that everybody involved is comfortable with) to a database + asp.net core web app solution (that would take considerable time and effort to build. Plus, no grid component matches the flexibility and features of "excel" spreadsheets, as far as I know.)
Any ideas?

I think this issue needs Google Apps Script to handle the updates from the partial spreadsheets to the master spreadsheet. The script should be able to locate the rows involved based on the keys so that you will only need to update 1 row at a time and not the whole master spreadsheet. I recommend using a normal script (not trigger based scripts like onEdit) to avoid Google Apps Script quotas (like runtime quota and trigger quota).

Also, can you provide minimal reproducible example in the form of a Google Sheets file so that community members may easily replicate your sample data.

1) roughly how many "partial spreadsheets"/salesman are there? 2) I can imaging an onEdit script but I doubt that salesman (as users) would have the right to access the "master spreadsheet"; but maybe there could be an intervening sheet that salesmen can update and which can then be updated to the master. (potential problem will onEdit be triggered for that intervening sheet?

How the copies are generated is of no concern to me -it's the director's job to do it This is unfortunate because an installable trigger might simplify the update process-Installable triggers always run under the account of the person who created them.. So if the director and/or you created an installable onedit trigger in each partial spreadsheet, then the script would be able to update the "master" directly since it would run under your/directors account.

How often are the partial spreadsheets created? Are new partial spreadsheets created, or is the content of an existing spreadsheet overwritten? If new, then are the previous copies still existent?

@PatrickdC I've updated the question to include the javascript code of the Apps Script that's supposed to update the cells of the master spreadsheet. The script is part of every partial spreadsheet. I've tested it with triggers which are totally unreliable. Can you please elaborate on when a "normal script" would run and how?

@Tedinoz 1) 15 2) I've tried the onEdit trigger but unfortunately it does not work in a consistent fashion. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I am not sure about access rights, though. The idea is that partials are generated by "us" and shared with salesmen. Any script/trigger should be there beforehand. In my tests I selected Extensions > Apps Scripts and added both the script and the trigger in every partial I created.

@Tedinoz Periodically but not in a fixed time period. Partials can be either created from scratch or re-used; either way would do.

I do apologize for the confusion. What I meant by normal script was to run a script manually that will serve as a submit button/feature for the partial spreadsheets to send to the master spreadsheet once the owners of the partial spreadsheets are done with their edits (to avoid multiple onEdit runs and avoid possible apps script quota). This will ensure the success of the update process. However, the owners of the partial spreadsheet must also have edit access to the master spreadsheet in order to send updates.

When values are edited the master spreadsheet should be updated to reflect the changes. How quickly should this happen? Immediately, once an hour, n times a day, etc?

To summarise: Is it possible to apply one-way sync between a master spreadsheet and partial copies of it using Google Sheets? Yes (tested and proven). Use an installable onEdit apps script. Trigger installation is done by you or the director (or someone with access to the "master") NOT the salesman. The script handles the update to "master" along with changing the background color. It runs under your/the directors account; the salesman has NO access to "master".  The only unknown relates to quotas=>Triggers total runtime=>"90 min/day" vs "6hr/day" depending on the account type.

You have a number of spreadsheets ("Partials") that are created from a master ("Master). As changes are made in any Partial, you want the change and an appropriate background color to be reflected in the Master.
Consider this answer:

in testing (with small record numbers), the Master is updated within a second of a valid Partial edit.
the script must be copied to the Project file of each Partial spreadsheet.
the script is be triggered in each partial spreadsheet by an installable onEdit trigger
The trigger MUST be installed by the OP or the Director or anyone who has access to the "Master". This is so that the script, when run, has access to the Master.

Based on my testing, the trigger must be installed manually; it is theoretically possible to manage/install the trigger from another spreadsheet but it appears that a bug renders this impossible.


Since salesmen are editors, they have access to the project file and the script.

There are options for using a library or an intermediate file to store the script so that salesmen are unable to view the detail of the script. The OP should consider whether this is desirable and research alternatives. There are many topics on StackOverflow covering these issues.



Logic
Processing is straightforward, nothing exotic and Event Objects are used.

Tests to confirm that the edit is made on the "appropriate" sheet name, row and column
The key on the edited Row is obtained; if there is no key, the edit is ignored.
Background colors are deined in an array.
The background color of the edited cell is updated.
indexOf is used to find a match for the key on "Master".

If no match can be found, there is provision for the OP to send a message or take other appropriate action.


The relevant cell on the "master is updated with the edited value and the background color is set.

Other considerations:

if a "partial" is updated by the Director, the script will be triggered, and the background color of both the "Partial" as well as the "Master" will be updated.


function updateMaster(e) {

  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG

  // get Event Objects
  var editedValue=e.value
  var editedSheet = e.range.getSheet().getName()
  var editedRow = e.range.rowStart
  var editedCol = e.range.columnStart
  var spreadsheetName = e.source.getName()

  // get variables
  var sheet2Watch = "Partial"

  // Logger.log("DEBUG: edited value = "+editedValue+", edited sheet = "+editedSheet+", edited row = "+editedRow+", edited Column = "+editedCol+", spreadsheet Name = "+spreadsheetName)
   if (editedSheet != sheet2Watch){
    // no match, do nothing
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: no match on sheet do nothing")
    return
  }
  else if ( editedRow < 2){
    // no match, do nothing
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: no match on row, do nothing")
    return
  }
  else if (editedCol !=2 && editedCol !=3){
    // no match, do nothing
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: no match on column, do nothing")
    return
  }

  // Logger.log("DEBUG: valid edit")
    
  // test for key in that row
  var partial = e.source.getSheetByName(sheet2Watch)
  var key = partial.getRange(editedRow,1).getValue()
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the key range = "+partial.getRange(editedRow,1).getA1Notation()+", and key = "+key+", key length = "+key.length)
  if (key.length !=0 ){
    // key exists
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: There's a key in this row")
  }
  else{
    // no key in this row, do nothing
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: no key in this row, do nothing")
    return
  }
  // get the colour to update
  var colors = ["#FAD437","#7CF926"]
  var updateColor = colors[editedCol-2]
  // update color of the edited cell
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the edited cell = "+partial.getRange(editedRow,editedCol).getA1Notation())
  partial.getRange(editedRow,editedCol).setBackground(updateColor)

  // get the master data
  var masterId = "<insert master ID>"
  var masterSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(masterId)
  var masterSheet = masterSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Master")
  // get master data
  var masterData = masterSheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  // remove the headers
  masterData.shift()
  // get column A (keys)
  var masterKeys = masterData.map(function(e){return e[0]})
  // Logger.log(masterKeys) // DEBUG
  // find the index of the partial key on the master
  var masterIndex = masterKeys.indexOf(key)
  if (masterIndex == -1){
    // if result = -1 then key not found
    // send message to someone.
    return
  }
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: key index on master = "+masterIndex)

  // get the range to update
  var masterUpdateRange = masterSheet.getRange((+masterIndex+2),editedCol)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Master range to update = "+masterUpdateRange.getA1Notation())

  // update the value and color in the Master  
  masterUpdateRange.setValue(editedValue).setBackground(updateColor)
}


BEFORE - Master

BEFORE - Partial


AFTER - Master

AFTER - Partial



